# CodeIgniter won't redirect after successful form validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, redirect

I'm kind of learning CodeIgniter as I go, since I had to take over a project from a team member who departed mid-project.  Overall I'm making good progress, but this one problem has me completely stumped.

As far as the basic structure goes, we've got the following:

```
/application/controllers/Dashboard.php

function add_record() {
    $locations = $this->db->get('locations');
    $location['loc_data'] = $locations->result_array();

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('dash/add_record', $location);
}

function create_record() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_first_name', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_last_name', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_email', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_phone', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_address', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_city', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_state', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_zip', NULL, 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_message', , 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('dash/add_record');
    }else{
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data = array(
            'customer_first_name' => $this->input->post('customer_first_name'),
            'customer_last_name' => $this->input->post('customer_last_name'),
            'customer_email' => $this->input->post('customer_email'),
            'customer_phone' => $this->input->post('customer_phone'),
            'customer_address' => $this->input->post('customer_address'),
            'customer_city' => $this->input->post('customer_city'),
            'customer_state' => $this->input->post('customer_state'),
            'customer_zip' => $this->input->post('customer_zip'),
            'customer_message' => $this->input->post('customer_message'),
            'status' => 1,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'created_on' => time(),
        );

        $this->db->insert('customer_message', $data);
        $this->send_status($data['customer_email'],$data['status'], $etext='', $data);
        redirect('dash/index', 'refresh');
    }

}


/application/dash/add_record.php
<?php $this->load->view('header');?>
 <?php echo form_open_multipart("dashboard/create_record",'id="my-record" style="width:100%;border:0;padding:0;"');?>
          <label>Customer First Name
            <?php echo form_input('customer_first_name', set_value('customer_first_name'), 'placeholder="Customer First Name" required');?>
          </label>
          <label>Customer Last Name
            <?php echo form_input('customer_last_name', set_value('customer_last_name'), 'placeholder="Customer First Name" required');?>
          </label>
          <label>Customer Email
            <?php echo form_input('customer_email', set_value('customer_email'), 'placeholder="Customer Email" required');?>
          </label>
          <label>Customer Phone
            <?php echo form_input('customer_phone', set_value('customer_phone'), 'placeholder="Customer Phone Number" required');?>
          </label>
          <label>Customer Address
            <?php echo form_input('customer_address', set_value('customer_address'), 'placeholder="Customer Address" required');?>
          </label>
          <label>Customer City
            <?php echo form_input('customer_city', set_value('customer_city'), 'placeholder="Customer City" required');?>
          </label>
          <label>Customer State
            <?php echo form_input('customer_state', set_value('customer_state'), 'placeholder="Customer State" required');?>
          </label>
          <label>Customer Zip Code
            <?php echo form_input('customer_zip', set_value('customer_zip'), 'placeholder="Customer Zip" required');?>
          </label>
        <label>Message
          <?php echo form_textarea('customer_message', set_value('customer_message'), 'placeholder="Message" required');?>
        </label>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" multiple/>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'id="submit-all" class="button"');?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
<?php $this->load->view('footer');?>
```

What ends up happening is the user submits the form and the validation takes place.  It's catching errors and forcing you to correct them, however if all of the fields check out then it's silently submitting the form in the background and adding the rows to the database while leaving the form up (it doesn't even appear to be reloading anything; there's no flickering).

If it were behaving properly, it would be going to the Dashboard index (/dash/index.php).

I've tried commenting out all of the `set_rules()` calls, but validation still takes place.  I've tried commenting out the `if/else` block and just forcing it to submit the data and redirect, but it still executes the validation and remains on the form looking as though nothing happened.

Other redirects in the project are working fine; this is the only one that's having an issue, and comparing the code there really doesn't seem to be any difference in structure.  What's going on here?

**==== EDIT ====**

Per request, here's the `send_status` function:

```
/application/controllers/Dashboard.php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    // [...]

    public function send_status($to,$status, $etext='', $template)
    {
        // load email library
        $this->load->library('email');
        if($etext==''){
            if($status == 1){
                $id = 1;
            }
            if($status == 2){
                $id = 3;
            }
            if($status == 3){
                $id = 2;
            }
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get('email');
            $mail = $query->row();  
            $etext = $mail->template;
        }
        if($status != 0){

            foreach($template as $key => $value){
                $etext = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $etext);
            }

            $this->email
                ->from($mail->sender_email, 'Company Name')
                ->to($to)
                ->subject('Your Submission')
                ->message($etext)
                ->set_mailtype('html');

            // send email
            $this->email->send();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need refresh parameter in `redirect()` function and be sure `dash/index` is `controller_name/action_name`.

Try this one: `redirect('Dashboard/index');` if index action exist in your dashboard controller.

Comment: `/application/views/dash/Dashboard.php You have got it as a view  that should be in controllers

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  It's in the proper location, I just typed it out wrong.  Fixing now.

Comment: if($this->email->send())
{
    return 1;
}

else
{
    return 0;
}     add this line

Comment: change from $this->form_validation->run() === FALSE to $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE and test

Comment: @AHJeebon: Both 'dash/function_name' and 'dashboard/function_name' are appearing in working redirects in the controller (the first uses the directory path, the second the controller name, I'm assuming?).  I've tried both, as well as with a capital 'Dashboard' as you have it, and it's behaving the same way each time.

Comment: @dhruvjadia: Same result

Comment: Also, just did a check of my inbox and found 45 new messages, so the e-mails are, in fact, sending.

Comment: Found the root cause of the issue; answer posted as a courtesy to those following the question.  Voting to close because the issue turned out to be something completely different from what it appeared at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason for the issue.  In addition to CodeIgniter's built-in form validation, the previous programmer had installed Parsley.js for form validation, which then proceeded to hijack the submit behavior, send an AJAX call to the page that processed the form data, and then neglected to do a redirect thereafter.  Removed the Parsley.js code and it's now running properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you described that data properly inserted that means no problem with this line.

```
$this->db->insert('customer_message', $data);
```

Change from

```
$this->send_status($data['customer_email'],$data['status'], $etext='', $data);
```

To

```
$result =$this->send_status($data['customer_email'],$data['status'], $etext='', $data);
if($result){
    redirect('dash/index', 'refresh');
}
```

Do it after changing

```
$this->email->send();
```

to

```
if($this->email->send())
{
    return 1;
}

else
{
    return 0;
}
```

**If problem with mail function then it will not redirect**

Comment: No change; same behavior as before.

Comment: @kaji : give send_status method in your question

Comment: Edited to add send_status

Comment: provide full Dashboard controller

Comment: @Kaji: Provided detailed answer

Comment: Just tested; it's still changing all fields to green and staying put.